# open id configuration issue with sitecore CLI

Tags: sitecore-cli

getting error while logging into VM with following command:

```
dotnet sitecore login --authority https://<sitecore-identity-server> --cm https://<sitecore-instance> --allow-write true --client-id <client-id>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Sumit's checklist. When you try to browse the URL  `https://qa1.url.com/.well-known/openid-configuration` and it does not return json then it could also be related to Sitecore license file.

You can find out identity server license file at `\Youridentityserver\sitecoreruntime\license.xml`. Try to change it with a valid license file and it should get resolved.

Reference: [SITECORE CLI LOGIN ERROR - /.well-known/openid-configuration](https://tekkishare.azurewebsites.net/pages/sitecore-clilogin-error-badgateway)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your Identity server is not working. When you copy the URL that is shown in the image i.e. `https://qa1.url.com/.well-known/openid-configuration` and open it in the browser, you will get a `JSON` response.

You need to check the following things.

1. Browse your Identity server URL and see if it's working properly or not.
2. Check the logs if it gives you some more context of the errors.
3. Check the entry in your host file. If it doesn't exist then it may give you an error like this.
4. Lastly, you need to find and install the correct `dotnet core` version to resolve it. To find `dotnet core` version, go to identity server root in `inetpub` folder. Open the `Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.runtimeconfig.json` file and check the `dotnet core` version. Now download the `dotnet core windows hosting bundle`. Go to https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet find the correct version. Download and install it. After installation go to IIS and recycle Identity Server App Pool.

Now check the identity server URL in browser. If you are able to see the CMS login screen successfully then your CLI issue also should resolve.

Refererence: https://www.stockpick.nl/english/sitecore-cli-login-error/

https://thedebugdude.com/sitecore-cli-error-connecting-to-well-known-openid-configuration-internal-server-error/

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am not getting JSON when go to https://qa1.url.com/.well-known/openid-configuration. looks like a problem with identity server only as I can see ?fbc=1 in login url. 

Cant we run sitecore CLi without identity server?